# DSP Filtering For Streaming

Tags: c++, filtering, signal-processing

I have a basic filter with FIR filter of 121 taps and a filter state length of 120. I can get it to work in matlab but I can't seem to understand what filter state to save. I look at the matlab filter state outside and it doesn't match and of the data_in. I am streaming data so I would need each iteration when put together to be equivalent to filtering everything at once.

```
for (int i = 0; i <16000; i++){
    for (int j = 0; j <121; j++){
    {
    if (j > i){
    data_out[out] += filter[j] * data_in[j - i];
    }
  }
}

memcpy(&filter_state_save[0], data_in[16000-120], 120*sizeof(data_in));
```

Isn't it normal for the filter state to be near of the end of the data_in?

Comment: `j - i` should be `i - j`.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is vague. Why would you need to save the input data and why do you just save the last 120 samples?

If I understood correctly, you are trying to save the output of the filter to the memory, to do more DSP on it perhaps?

- Your first 120 samples would contain the filter response.
- Save the data_out with (input_samples-filter_order) samples starting from index input_samples. Since the signal is delayed by the filter_order amount.

  ```
  for (int i = 0; i <16000; i++){
      for (int j = 0; j <121; j++){
      {
      if (i > j){ // changed case
      data_out[out] += filter[j] * data_in[i - j]; // should be i-j
      }
    }
  }

  memcpy(filter_state_save[0], data_in, 16000*sizeof(data_in)); 
  // copy 16000 elements back to filter_state_save which is the filtered output                        
  // output.
  ```

  - Make sure you allocate memory to filter_state_save as 2D array since you will be copying 16000 elements to 0th index. For the next filter you probably want to copy to 1st index.

Hope this helps.